# Opening external files (docs, picttures, ...) form commentlines in VisualStudio 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

In Visual Studio 2013 i used to define in a commentline something like this
"file:\d:\MACHINE\Elumatec_610.doc"
and the file opened automatically by CTRL-Key and MouseCLick on it.
I have many references to WORD-Documents, Pdf, Pictures, eMails and more.

In Visual Studio 2022 this function does not work any more.
I get an Error Message.

How can i format the commentline for opening again the requested documents ?

TankYou very much

I tried many alternative calls... but didn't found the correct one.

Comment: Please tell us what the error message says. This feature still works for me in VS2022

Comment: I find I have to use file:// as the prefix and use forward slashes not backslashes, but apart from that it works for me in VS2022